# 'unrecognized selector' received when trying to display recipes list in Navigation table view

Tags: ios

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:      (NSInteger)section
{
return [recieps count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [recieps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

I want to display recipes list in Navigation table view but I am getting errors like `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c61709f80`

Comment: In which line you are getting 'crashed'?

Comment: Which line exactly ? Show the whole error message. You are not giving the selector (method name to simplify) nor the class of the object that received it and doesn't implement it.

Comment: 2016-05-24 20:56:15.252 NavigationController[4145:320355] Unknown class _TtC3RVC14ViewController in Interface Builder file.
2016-05-24 20:56:16.197 NavigationController[4145:320355] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec31c38af0
2016-05-24 20:56:16.202 NavigationController[4145:320355] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec31c38af0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: First resolve **Unknown class _TtC3RVC14ViewController in Interface Builder file**. It means, somewhere a view controller is set to the custom class `ViewController` but the class does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

"Unrecognized Selector" in iOS means you're attempting to call a method that the object you're asking doesn't understand.

You're saying `[someObject doThisMethod]`, but someObject doesn't know what you're talking about.

Either the method doesn't exist for that object & needs to be added, or there's an issue with your storyboard connections or classes.

The error tells you what the problem is & where:

```
 -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec31c38af0
```

This tells you that a tableView instance (at memory address 0x7fec31c38af0) received the message `numberOfRowsInSection:`, but it doesn't know what to do.

If you're using a custom class for your UITableView, make sure you've set it properly in your storyboard. Also make sure you've properly hooked up both `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Since it doesn't recognize this required `UITableViewDataSource` protocol method, it's likely you forgot to add that or hook it up. Double-check your storyboard connections and that your UITableView class actually conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Also, it's "recipe" ... you have misspelled it "recieps" in several places...

Answer (score -1):

In your above code number of section method not called. Please add the below line of code

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
  }

Note:
Then you are calling some method that is not exist in your controller.That's why you got the 'unrecognized selector' error message on console. Try to figure out the method and check again.

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is an optional `UITableViewDataSource` protocol method. It's not included here, but that's not the cause of the error.